# DevExtreme dxRadioGroup default selectedIndex issue

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, devexpress, devextreme

Iam using DevExtreme 14.2 version, am not able to set default value on dxRadioGroup. consider the following code i don't know where i did mistake.

HTML:

```
      <div data-bind="dxRadioGroup: { dataSource: items, layout: 'horizontal', value: defaultvalue, valueExpr: 'this' }"></div>
```

JS:

```
 dxSample_13_2.home = function (params) {

  var viewModel = {
    items: [
        { text: "Tea" },
        { text: "Coffee" },
        { text: "juice" }
    ],
    defaultvalue: ko.observable(items[2]),
  }

  return viewModel; 
 };
```

Comment: Have you tried using the value binding?

Comment: through value binding also it wont works

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in the documentation. I'd suggest to ask DevExtreme themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an error in your code. There is no `items` variable that you try to access.

```
var items = [
        { text: "Tea" },
        { text: "Coffee" },
        { text: "juice" }
    ];

var viewModel = {
    items: items,
    defaultvalue: ko.observable(items[2])
};
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/tfvtq9y0/